# Prestashop - index.php?controller=404 in module

Tags: php, redirect, module, prestashop

I've published module in Prestashop Addons(PrestaShop 1.6), it works just fine on my local environment as well as on production environment and couple of customers already installed it.

I'm using module front controllers to navigate inside my module (on admin panel side using friendly links, UI build in vue.js) for example domain.com/mymodulename/login, domain.com/mymodulename/logout, etc...

But there is this one customer's platform (friendly links tured on) where my module is hitting any of requested url mentioned above, but immediately is redirected to domain.com/lang/index.php?controller=404 with 404 status.

I cannot reproduce the problem on my local environment -
htaccess file below :

```
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On

RewriteEngine on

#Domain: presta.platformname.com
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %

{ENV:REWRITEBASE}
webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

Images
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9])?/.\.jpg$ % {ENV:REWRITEBASE}
img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9])?/.\.jpg$ %

{ENV:REWRITEBASE}
img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9])?/.\.jpg$ %

{ENV:REWRITEBASE}
img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9])?/.\.jpg$ %

{ENV:REWRITEBASE}
img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9])?/.\.jpg$ %

{ENV:REWRITEBASE}
img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9])?/.\.jpg$ %

{ENV:REWRITEBASE}
img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9])?/.\.jpg$ %

{ENV:REWRITEBASE}
img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9])?/.\.jpg$ %

{ENV:REWRITEBASE}
img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9])(-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9])?/.+\.jpg$ %

{ENV:REWRITEBASE}
img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-])(-[0-9])?/.+\.jpg$ %

{ENV:REWRITEBASE}
img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]

AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]
Dispatcher
RewriteCond % {REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}
-l [OR]
RewriteCond %

{REQUEST_FILENAME}
-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %

{ENV:REWRITEBASE}
index.php [NC,L]

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/font-woff .woff
AddType font/woff2 .woff2

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404
```

Comment: Are you sure the .htaccess configurations of the server are correct and mod_rewrite is on? (this is for Apache only)

Comment: It's on Apache and I've added .htaccess conf to the post above. It seems like mod_revrite is on, but I still get - ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404